# Getting Specific thing from a string

Tags: javascript

I have a button which looks like this

```
  <button aria-label="Connect with Yam Jeji" data-control-name="srp_profile_actions" class="search-result__actions--primary button-secondary-medium m5" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6020="6020" data-is-animating-click="true">
```

Inside the button we have `aria-label` which looks like this..

```
aria-label="Connect with Yam Jeji"
```

Now, In this I just want to select/get name `Yam Jeji`

How can I achieve this using javascript? For example I have multiple button with different names and the names aren't static i.e our aria-label can be something like

```
aria-label="Connect with Yam Jeji"
aria-label="Connect with Varun Bidhu"
aria-label="Connect with Yaon Titu"
```

How can I just get names here (the Connect is static here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly get what you mean, but if you take the string in the aria label, split it at "Connect With ", & pop that, you will get the names.

ex.

```
buttonText = "Connect With Yam Jeji"

buttonText.split("Connect With ").pop();

console.log(buttonText);
```

It will output "Yam Jeji"

Comment: The issue with this answer is this doesn't get the name if there are multiple buttons on one page.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option
1. Using querySelector get all elements.
2. Loop through array of elements.
3. Using getAttribute method to fetch aria-label values.
4.Use split and pop to get specific word.

```js
var ariaTxt = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label]');

ariaTxt.forEach(v =>{
  console.log(v.getAttribute('aria-label').split("Connect with ").pop())
})
```

```html
  <button aria-label="Connect with Yam Jeji" data-control-name="srp_profile_actions" class="search-result__actions--primary button-secondary-medium m5" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6020="6020" data-is-animating-click="true">
```

code sample- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/KeGjrZ

Answer (score 0):

1) add  onClick in button

```
<button onclick="teste(this)" aria-label="Connect with Yam Jeji" data-control-name="srp_profile_actions" class="search-result__actions--primary button-secondary-medium m5" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6020="6020" data-is-animating-click="true">
 teste</button>
```

2) Add this funtion above

```
<script>
        function teste(inp){
            var ariaLabel =  inp.getAttribute("aria-label");
            ariaLabel = ariaLabel.replace("Connect with ", "");
            alert(ariaLabel);

        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly more robust jQuery solution with a regular expression: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/316543/

```
var ariaList = $("button[aria-label*='Connect with ']");

ariaList.each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('aria-label').match(/Connect with (.*)/)[1]);
});
```

It is also compatible with older browsers that don't have es6 (like IE11).